# function's returned value lost after decorated by other function

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

```
def myfunc():
    print(" myfunc() called.")
    return 'ok'
```

The 'ok' was  function's returned value.

```
>>> myfunc()
 myfunc() called.
'ok'
```

Now to decorate it with other function.
The decorate function.

```
def deco(func):
    def _deco():
        print("before myfunc() called.")
        func()
        print("  after myfunc() called.")
    return _deco
```

To decorate myfunc with deco function.

```
@deco
def myfunc():
    print(" myfunc() called.")
    return 'ok'

>>> myfunc()
before myfunc() called.
 myfunc() called.
  after myfunc() called.
```

Why the result is not as following?

```
>>> myfunc()
before myfunc() called.
 myfunc() called.
'ok'
  after myfunc() called.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call the undecorated `myfunc` function in the shell, it prints the returned value automatically. After the decoration, `myfunc` is set to the `_deco` function which only returns `None` implicitly and doesn't print the returned value of `myfunc`, so `'ok'` doesn't appear in the shell anymore.

If you want to print `'ok'`, you have to do it in the `_deco` function:

```
def deco(func):
    def _deco():
        print("before myfunc() called.")
        returned_value = func()
        print(returned_value)
        print("  after myfunc() called.")
    return _deco
```

And if you want to return the value you have to return it from `_deco`:

```
def deco(func):
    def _deco():
        print("before myfunc() called.")
        returned_value = func()
        print("  after myfunc() called.")
        return returned_value
    return _deco
```